# Use of cores with `isolcpus` and `cpuset`

Tags: linux, cgroup

I have a Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.9 (Santiago) (I don't manage it). In the GRUB config file I have, let's say, `isolcpus=2-32` (out of 36 cores). I also have a cgroup with `cpuset=2-32` assigned via `cgset.conf` to all important processes on that system.

My question is: how do these 2 settings interact?

Normally when I start a process with `taskset -c 2-32` all threads end up on core 2 as isolcpus "removes cores from scheduler" as I was told so there is no load balancing.

However, the observed effect of cpuset is different - the various processes and threads end up on different cores.

Could someone explain how `isolcpus` and `taskset` command produces one result, while `isolcpus` and cgroups/cpusets produce a different one?